How to edit text of a Text Label on joining a game
I've been trying to help my friend making a randomized title screen splash (like in Minecraft or Terraria) but I've been having some problems with having the text actually change. I've tried a few different methods but none of them have worked so far, these are:

Having everything set up in 1 local script within the main text variable I'm editing with (It prints both the randomized splash number and complete but doesn't change the actual text on the label)

local text = game.StarterGui.MainMenu.splash
local splashText = text.Text
local splash = math.random(1,2)
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.splash

print(splash)
    
if splash == 1 then
    splashText = "a"
    print("Complete")
elseif splash == 2 then
    splashText = "b"
    print("Complete")
end


Having two different scripts linked with a RemoteEvent, one in "StarterPlayerScripts" and the other in the main element I'm trying to change. All 3 print commands printed to the output log but the text did not change.

Script 1 (Local Script):
local splash = math.random(2,3)
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.splash

print(splash)
event:FireServer(splash)

Script 2 (Normal Script):
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.splash

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, splash)
    print(splash)
    local text = plr.PlayerGui.MainMenu.splash
    local splashText = text.Text
    if splash == 1 then
        splashText = "a"
                print("Complete")
    elseif splash == 2 then
        splashText = "b"
        print("Complete")
       end
end)


I've replaced the "game.StarterGui.MainMenu.splash" with "game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Mainmenu.splash". It prints all the commands but doesn't change the text.

local text = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.MainMenu.splash
local splashText = text.Text
local splash = math.random(1,2)
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.splash

print(splash)
    
if splash == 1 then
    splashText = "a"
    print("Complete")
elseif splash == 2 then
    splashText = "b"
    print("Complete")
end


I've tried replacing the variable of "splashText" to be just "text.Text" in both scripts but that also just printed all commands.

local text = game.StarterGui.MainMenu.splash
local splash = math.random(1,2)
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.splash

print(splash)
    
if splash == 1 then
    text.Text = "a"
    print("Complete")
elseif splash == 2 then
    text.Text = "b"
    print("Complete")
end

Is there any way anybody knows of making this work?

You have to consider that everything in game.StarterGui is cloned to the PlayerGui. Right now you are changing the game.StarterGui.TextLabel but not the one in game.Players.<playername>.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.<...>.
The file structure is as follows
StarterGui
| ScreenGui
| | Frame
| | | TextLabel
| | | | LocalScript

I've used a Frame, but structure as you wish.
LocalScript
local textLabel = script.Parent
local splashTexts = {"foo", "bar"}
textLabel.Text = splashTexts[math.random(1, #splashTexts)]
-- uses the length syntax, #, for length of table

Every player will have a different splash text and this will also change every time they respawn (as the PlayerGui is remade every-time they respawn). If this is a problem you can store it as an attribute on the LocalPlayer.
local textLabel = script.Parent
local splashTexts = {"foo", "bar"}
local localPlayer = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local chosenText = localPlayer:GetAttribute("SplashText")
if (chosenText == nil) then
    chosenText = splashTexts[math.random(1, #splashTexts)]
    localPlayer:SetAttribute("SplashText", chosenText)
end
textLabel.Text = chosenText

